# Java program hangs on executeUpdate without exception

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a simple program that does database update using Oracle Driver. It is a long running sql that works in SQLDeveloper mode but hang on executing in Java program:

```
String sql = "UPDATE ...";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
log.info(sql);

int affectedRows = ps.executeUpdate();
log.info("affected rows = " + affectedRows);
```

It logs the sql line, but never prints the affected rows line.

In the database it shows the execution (`V$SESSION_LONGOPS`)  is completed with 0 remaining time:

[image]

However weird thing is this session only exists in `V$SESSION_LONGOPS` but not `V$SESSION`. And apparently this never gets back to the Java program. In the running system of the program, `ps -ef` gives this info:

```
user 5889  5885  0 00:00 ?        00:00:11 /java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java -cp ...
```

It shows it started running at 00.00 (scheduled by Cron) and only executed for 11 seconds (and now it is 10am which 10h has passed). It seems like the program just hangs/dies, and no exception is given in the log (a big try catch is surrounded with log exception).

It never reaches to the end of program because ps still prints this and there is no logs of the coming line.

Would appreciate any help that points to the direction.

Comment: At first blush it appears that the database session got disconnected somehow.

Comment: @BobJarvis I suspect the same, but no exception is really weird.

Comment: If the session dropped from the server end or there was a network problem then it's feasible the Java side has a long timeout and just hasn't noticed yet. Is there anything in the server alert log of SQL\*Net log that indicates a problem? (Also bear in mind the 11 seconds is total CPU time for that Java process so far, not elapsed real time, and doesn't include any CPU time on the database as that's handles by separate processes).

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for the  help! I found a very old transaction that is still alive... Surprised the session is not showing in longops table but still alive!

Comment: Is that old transaction blocking, or being blocked, by an uncommitted change? Maybe from you trying the update manually somewhere and leaving that session alive without rolling back, say? Look in the dba_waiters and dba_blockers views if you have access, though you need to session info to make sense of anything that returns really.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes that was when I updated in SQLDeveloper and did not commit. I thought it would automatically rollback when the session is disconnected but apparently it did not. Maybe I am getting something wrong.

Comment: Depends how/when it disconnected maybe. If SQL Developer exited or you lost network something it could have been left hanging? You might need to kill the session from the database ([alter system kill session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc008.htm#ADMIN11192)), if you have privs to do that, and being very careful what you kill of course... Your Java program may spring back to life, if it hasn't timed out or been killed by now.

Comment: Are other sessions accessing the same database simultaneously? A am thinking this could be due to table or row level locking on the database side.

Answer (score 5):

You can check below tables whether your session is in waiting mode or not.

select * from dba_blockers;
select * from dba_waiters;

Make sure your session is not in above query.

and also check whether your objects is not locked with below query

select * from v$locked_object in this view you can get locked object id and from dba_objects you are able to get object name.

if you found any session in this then please kill or finish that session first.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem you had, 
I don't know about others but I solved it by simply closing SQLplus!
I didn't think that could solve it since some queries worked while sqlplus was running on the console, but I closed it and now every queries work and nothing hangs!

You may want to try this if you have our problem!

Comment: I am using an Oracle database and also had it open. Closing it also allowed mine to run, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. executeUpdate was just hanging and there was no error.

The problem: I was at the same time connected with sqlDeveloper to the same db and had the same table open. As soon as I disconnected sqlDeveloper from the DB, the statements could be inserted and the java application went on working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

1. Set a timeout in your SQL
2. Check if after a timeout your update still was effective and changed any row.
3. Use VisualVM and Debugger to check what the Driver is doing on the client

You need to check what your application is doing. First of all you can set the Timeout for the statement about to be executed. If you set it to 20seconds you can simply generate a SQLTimeoutException on the client side.

Using try {} catch(SQLTimeoutException e) {} you can print your a notification. Next thing you can create a statement to check whether or not your sql has been executed.

What is the typical SQL Developer timing and why does it take so long? Can you give us the SQL and Table Structure? Any Triggers, do you update a view or a concrete table?

The next thing you can do is using VisualVM and create thread dumps while your SQL is hanging. Increase the timeout to 60seconds and create ThreadDumps. There you see what the threads are doing and if Oracle Driver waits for a socket connection than indeed it is waiting for the Database to responde. If you see different behaviour you might guess what is going on.

Another idea is running your application in debug mode. Wait 30seconds (timeout still 60seconds) and pause the application and check the thread managing the connection. What is he doing where and why. If I remember correctly you can optain the source for the oracle driver. If not just decompile the code using JD or something similar or just read the byte code... .